# How to define and invoke a partially applied function with varargs?

Tags: scala

Stack Over Flow:

Hi all.

I would like to define a partially applied function which has varargs.

To confirm, I prepared several functions i.e. Functions._.
The functions except func have a varargs argument.

How to define and invoke a partially applied function with varargs?
(e.g. gunc1 with varargs.)

java version "1.7.0_07"
Scala code runner version 2.9.1.final

```
object Functions {
    def func(x: Int, y: Int) = x + y
    def gunc(x: Int*) = x.sum
    def hunc(x: Int, y: Int*) = x + y.sum
    def iunc(x: Int)(y: Int*) = x + y.sum // curried
    def junk(x: String, y: Int*) = x + y.sum
}

object PartiallyApplied extends App {
    import Functions._

    val func0 = func(1, _: Int) // I can.
    println("result: " + func0(2))

    val gunc0 = gunc(1, _: Int) // I can invoke if I specify the varargs.size. But gunc0 no longer has varargs...
    println("result: " + gunc0(2))

//    val gunc1 = gunc(1, _: Int*) => compile error: ')' expected but identifier found.
//    val gunc1 = gunc(1, _: Seq[Int]) => compile error: type mismatch | found: Seq[Int] | required: Int
    val gunc1 = gunc(1, _: Int) // I can invoke if I specify the varargs.size. But gunc1 no longer has varargs...
    println("result: " + gunc1(2))

//    val hunc0 = hunc(1)_ => compile error: _ must follow method; cannot follow Int
//    val hunc0 = hunc(1, _: Int*) => compile error: ')' expected but identifier found.
//    val hunc0 = hunc(1, _: Seq[Int]) => compile error: type mismatch | found: Seq[Int] | required: Int
    val hunc0 = hunc(1, _: Int) // I can invoke if I specify the varargs.size. But hunc0 no longer has varargs...
    println("result: " + hunc0(2))
//    println("result: " + hunc0(2, 3)) => compile error: too many arguments for method apply: (v1: Int)Int in trait Function1
//    println("result: " + hunc0((2, 3): _*)) => compile error: type mismatch | found: (Int, Int) | required: Seq[Int]
//    println("result: " + hunc0(Seq(2, 3))) => compile error: type mismatch | found: Seq[Int] | required: Int
//    println("result: " + hunc0(Seq(2, 3): _*)) => compile error: no `: _*' annotation allowed here (such annotations are only allowed in arguments to *-parameters)

    val hunc1 = hunc(1, _: Int, _: Int) // I can invoke if I specify the varargs.size. But hunc1 no longer has varargs...
    println("result: " + hunc1(2, 3))

    val hunc2 = hunc(1, _: Int, _: Int, _:Int) // I can invoke if I specify the varargs.size. But hunc2 no longer has varargs...
    val hunc3 = hunc2(2, _: Int, _: Int)
    val hunc4 = hunc3(3, _: Int)
    println("result: " + hunc4(4))

    println("result: " + hunc5(2, 3))

//    val iunc0 = iunc(1)(_: Int*) => compile error: ')' expected but identifier found.
//    val iunc0 = iunc(1)(_: Seq[Int]) => compile error: type mismatch | found: Seq[Int] | required: Int
    val iunc0 = iunc(1)(_: Int)
    println("result: " + iunc0(2))

    val iunc1 = iunc(1)(_: Int, _: Int)
    println("result: " + iunc1(2, 3))
}

object NotPartiallyApplied extends App {
    import Functions._

    println("result: " + gunc(1))
    println("result: " + gunc(1, 2, 3))
    println("result: " + gunc(Seq(1, 2, 3): _*))

    println("result: " + hunc(1))
    println("result: " + hunc(1, 2, 3))
    println("result: " + hunc(1, Seq(2, 3): _*))

    println("result: " + iunc(1)(2, 3))
    println("result: " + iunc(1)(Seq(2, 3): _*))

    println("result: " + junk("x"))
    println("result: " + junk("x", 2, 3))
    println("result: " + junk("x", Seq(2, 3): _*))
}
```

[Edit after Rex Kerr's comment]

I want the partially applied function like guncN below:

```
val guncN = gunc(1, _: Int*)
println("result: " + guncN(2)) // => 3
println("result: " + guncN(2, 3)) // => 6
println("result: " + guncN(2, 3, 4, 5, 100)) // => 115
```

But it is prohibited by scalac.

I think guncN should be evaluated each time, at time (2), (2, 3), and (2, 3, 4, 5, 100) are given.
We don't need guncM below:

```
val guncM = guncN(2, _: Int*)
println("result: " + guncM(3, 4)) // => 10
```

Answer (score 6):

If you just want varargs, you can in 2.9:

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.9.1.final
(Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_31).
...
scala>     def sum(xs: Int*) = xs.sum
sum: (xs: Int*)Int

scala>     val summer = sum _
summer: Int* => Int = <function1>

scala> summer(1,2,3)
res0: Int = 6
```

But not in 2.10 as it stands now, and there's no apparent plan to change this: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4176

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.0-RC2
(Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_31).
...

scala> def sum(xs: Int*) = xs.sum
sum: (xs: Int*)Int

scala> val summer = sum _
summer: Seq[Int] => Int = <function1>

scala> summer(1,2,3)
<console>:10: error: too many arguments for method apply:
(v1: Seq[Int])Int in trait Function1
              summer(1,2,3)
```

If you have 2.9, then you can

```
scala> def temp(early: Int*)(rest: Int*) = sum((early ++ rest): _*)
temp: (i: Int, j: Int)(rest: Int*)Int

scala> val presummed = temp(1,2) _
presummed: Int* => Int = <function1>

scala> presummed(4,5)
res1: Int = 12
```

but perhaps you shouldn't count on having varargs functions since that seems to have been deprecated (or at least moved behind the `-Yeta-expand-keeps-star` flag, which as a `-Y` option may fail to work or be removed at any time).

Comment: [Rex Kerr] Thank you for reply. The function summer is just sum.
My gunc0 is not gunc. Its difference is gunc0 has 1(Int) as the first argument (gunc not). The function temp has two Int args BEFOREHAND. I want a partial function which we don't know args.size BEFOREHAND. regards.

Comment: Replies shouldn't go in answers--I admit that SO is weird in not allowing new users to comment on answers to their own questions.  Anyway, I've fixed it so you don't know how many args you have beforehand.  I'm assuming that you want to have a variable number afterwards also.  If not, please edit your question to give clear examples of code you should be able to write and what the answers should be.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out ambiguous. I edited the initial question.

Answer (score 2):

The solution I found is by composing functions :

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.0-RC1 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_37).
...
scala> 1 :: (_:Int) :: Nil : Seq[Int]
res42: Int => Seq[Int] = <function1>

scala> gunc _
res43: Seq[Int] => Int = <function1>

scala> res42 andThen res43
res54: Int => Int = <function1>

scala> res54(5)
res56: Int = 6
```

Comment: Thank you for reply.
But I cannot compile you cpde...
Which version is Scala? `scala> res0 andThen res1`
`<console>:11: error: type mismatch;`
`found : Int* => Int`
`required: Seq[Int] => ?`
`res0 andThen res1`

Answer (score 0):

> perhaps you shouldn't count on having varargs functions since that seems to have been deprecated (or at least moved behind the `-Yeta-expand-keeps-star` flag)

[SI-6816](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6816) confirms the deprecation, and in Scala 2.12.x, Dec. 2016, with [PR 5558](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/5558), that flag is definitively gone ([discussion here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/scala-internals/03Is9E42sRg/Nr4eG_FVCWIJ)).

> I want a partial function which we don't know `args.size` BEFOREHAND

That still does not seem possible (in Scala 2.12.x, Dec. 2016)