# Define and invoke partially applied function with varargs?

Tags: scala

There is something odd about partially applying a curried function with varargs. Consider this example:

```
def adder(a: Int)(b: Int*) = b.map(_ + a) 

adder(1)(1,2,3,4)     // res1: Seq[Int] = ArrayBuffer(2, 3, 4, 5)
val add2 = adder(2) _ // add2: Seq[Int] => Seq[Int]
add2(1,2,3,4)         // Fails to compile
add2(Seq(1,2,3,4)     // res3: Seq[Int] = List(3, 4, 5, 6)
```

While I am aware of a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13322930/706557), I would still like to know why the compiler does this and if there is some clever solution in these cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because methods and functions are different things in Scala. Methods support type parameters, default and named arguments, varargs, implicit argument lists, etc.

When you do eta expansion `method _`, the method is converted to a function which is simply an instance of a `Function0` to `Function22` trait, and doesn't support any of those features.

You can express function types with a shorthand `Int => String`, or `(A, B) => R`. Methods on the other hand have [non-value types](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html#non-value-types), and there is no general way to reference such a type in a Scala program.

If you want to have a callable variable, that supports varargs, or any other method features, you can return an object with an appropriate `apply` method:

```
case class adder(a: Int) {
  def apply(b: Int*) = b.map(_ + a)
}
```

Now it works:

```
scala> adder(1)(1,2,3,4)
res1: Seq[Int] = ArrayBuffer(2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> val add2 = adder(2)
add2: adder = adder(2)

scala> add2(1,2,3,4)
res2: Seq[Int] = ArrayBuffer(3, 4, 5, 6)
```